# cups (cupsd) broke when I removed colord - how to print without colord?

Tags: printing, cups, d-bus

Since a recent update, the cups daemon will not print anything anymore, silently queuing but not handling print jobs.  When looking for the reason I have found lines like

```
Oct 08 17:14:16 host dbus-daemon[1711]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ColorManager' unit='colord.service' requested by ':1.441' (uid=0 pid=30364 comm="/usr/sbin/cupsd -l ")
Oct 08 17:14:16 host dbus-daemon[1711]: [system] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'colord.service': Unit colord.service not found.
Oct 08 17:14:16 host dbus-daemon[1711]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ColorManager' unit='colord.service' requested by ':1.441' (uid=0 pid=30364 comm="/usr/sbin/cupsd -l ")
Oct 08 17:14:16 host dbus-daemon[1711]: [system] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'colord.service': Unit colord.service not found.
Oct 08 17:14:16 host dbus-daemon[1711]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ColorManager' unit='colord.service' requested by ':1.441' (uid=0 pid=30364 comm="/usr/sbin/cupsd -l ")
Oct 08 17:14:16 host dbus-daemon[1711]: [system] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'colord.service': Unit colord.service not found.
Oct 08 17:14:16 host dbus-daemon[1711]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ColorManager' unit='colord.service' requested by ':1.441' (uid=0 pid=30364 comm="/usr/sbin/cupsd -l ")
Oct 08 17:14:16 host dbus-daemon[1711]: [system] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'colord.service': Unit colord.service not found.
```

I also get lines like the following in `/var/log/cups/error_log`:

```
W [08/Oct/2019:17:14:16 +0200] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit:Unit colord.service not found.
W [08/Oct/2019:17:14:16 +0200] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit:Unit colord.service not found.
W [08/Oct/2019:17:14:16 +0200] CreateDevice failed: org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit:Unit colord.service not found.
```

though these are marked "W" as in "warning" - no errors?

There is no `colord` on my system, I have removed the service because (a) I do not need it and (b) it was initiating unsolicited connections and broadcasts in my home network.  So, re-enabling `colord` will not a solution for me.

**How do I print using `cupsd` without the use of `colord`?**

Tried fix:

Tried to re-install `colord` and starting it just for this print job.  The new error message I get is:

```
Oct 08 18:10:43 host colord[2742]: failed to get session [pid 2826]: No data available
```

Which means that `colord` is running but still not telling `cupsd` "just go ahead printing, there is no colour profile for this printer" (there isn't, and I do not need one for a black+white text document in the queue right now, or ever).

Comment: "_I have removed the service because [...] I do not need it_". Clearly you do need it, otherwise you wouldn't have asked the question. On the other hand, I can see that you do not want to have to install it again.

Comment: @roaima You are right, I probably should have said "I do not need the main service it offers - which is not useless dbus communication, but setting colour profiles".  I do not need colour profiles. At all.

Comment: Looks like it's not directly `colord` generating the network traffic, but `libsane`, with which it communicates. Look at https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=104465 and https://gitlab.com/sane-project/backends/issues/130, which between them give you a set of ports for which you could block outgoing traffic from your system. This doesn't answer your question, but it may help towards it.

Comment: @roima Thanks, I have blocked almost all outgoing traffic but do not fancy the noise in the logs without any benefit for me. Also, hardening a system means removing anything you do not need, which for me includes anything to do with colour profiles. Perhaps we will find a cups option or I need to downgrade?

Comment: Don't know, sorry. I'm watching with interest.